# Reactjs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventSlots' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am creating a calendar with events using reactjs, Now when the calendar shows the current month, when I click next its shows the April month if I click again next I get the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventSlots' of undefined.

[image]

The error appears in a function where I try to get days with the event here its.

```
  getDaysWithEvents() {
        // Get all the days in this months calendar view
        // Sibling Months included
        const days = this.getCalendarDays();

        // Set Range Limits on calendar
        this.calendar.setStartDate(days[0]);
        this.calendar.setEndDate(days[days.length - 1]);

        // Iterate over each of the supplied events
        this.props.events.forEach((eventItem) => {

            const eventStart = this.getCalendarDayObject(eventItem.start);
            const eventEnd = this.getCalendarDayObject(eventItem.end);
            const eventMeta = this.getEventMeta(days, eventStart, eventEnd);

            if (eventMeta.isVisibleInView) {
                const eventLength = eventMeta.visibleEventLength;

                console.log("Days", days); 

                const eventSlotIndex = days[eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex].eventSlots.indexOf(false); // this line returns error
                //console.log("eventSotsindex", eventSlotIndex);
                let dayIndex = 0;

                // For each day in the event
                while (dayIndex < eventLength) {
                    // Clone the event object so we acn add day specfic data
                    const eventData = Object.assign({}, eventItem);

                    if (dayIndex === 0) {
                         // Flag first day of event
                        eventData.isFirstDay = true;
                    }

                    if (dayIndex === eventLength - 1) {
                        // Flag last day of event
                        eventData.isLastDay = true;
                    }

                    if (!eventData.isFirstDay || !eventData.isLastDay) {
                        // Flag between day of event
                        eventData.isBetweenDay = true;
                    }

                    // Apply Event Data to the correct slot for that day
                   //console.log(eventMeta, dayIndex, days);

                    if (days[eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex + dayIndex]) {
                       if (days[eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex + dayIndex].eventSlots) {
                            days[eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex + dayIndex].eventSlots[eventSlotIndex] = eventData;

                       }
                    }

                    // Move to next day of event
                    dayIndex++;
                }
            }
        });

        return days;
    }
```

The line of code causing the problem : `const eventSlotIndex = days[eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex].eventSlots.indexOf(false);`

> NOTE: If someone wishes here is a repository with full code [calenar
>   demo](https://github.com/throne1986/Calendar), `clone`, `npm install` and `npm start`

What do I need to do to solve the problem? any help or contributions will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you console.log(eventMeta) before the problematic line? I tried reproducing the issue locally, but I seem to have compilation errors ("Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap/PopOver'")

Comment: those u can remove there just there for css , but I will send you screen now just a minute

Comment: @oneturkmen here u go https://ibb.co/1JmwzWy

Comment: The issue is that `eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex` exceeds the length of your array. For example, in my case (I managed to compile it), the length of `days` is 42, while `eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex` is 56. Clearly, this returns `undefined`.

Comment: Is this line of code correct: `firstVisibleDayIndex: eventStartInView ? Calendar.interval(firstDayOfMonth, eventStart) - 1 : 0,
`?

Comment: @oneturkmen in my side I think its correct  but not sure that is why I need help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210500/discussion-between-oneturkmen-and-user9964622).

Comment: You need to add data to your `days` array the further you go back. You can't just clear out `days` and refresh it with the currently-selected month.

Comment: @Ringo can you show it via code as an answer ?

Comment: I don't have the time, but think about this way: If you're trying to look ahead 56 days, you need to have a `days` array that's at least 56 items long. I think you must understand this. When you go forward a month, push data on the `days` array to make it longer

Comment: Try the good old `var eventSlotIndex = ...`
p.s.: Your program seems to be convinced that there's not going to be a month of May. :)

Comment: @BekimBacaj nah bro , crone the repo and try it yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex` goes out of bounds (i.e., `eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex` is greater than or equal to `days.length`).

A workaround would be to reset the first day index to 0 as follows:

```js
const firstDayIndex = eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex < days.length ? eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex : 0;

const eventSlotIndex = days[firstDayIndex].eventSlots.indexOf(false);
```